# Is there a parsing of bool like int in Dart?

Tags: string, dart, boolean

In `Dart`, there is a convenience method for converting a `String` to an `int`:

```
int i = int.parse('123');
```

Is there something similar for converting `String` to `bool`?

```
bool b = bool.parse('true');
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Bool has no methods.

```dart
var val = 'True';
bool b = val.toLowerCase() == 'true';
```

should be easy enough.

With recent Dart versions with extension method support the code could be made look more like for `int`, `num`, `float`.

```dart
extension BoolParsing on String {
  bool parseBool() {
    return this.toLowerCase() == 'true';
  }
}
  

void main() {
  bool b = 'tRuE'.parseBool();
  print('${b.runtimeType} - $b');
}
```

See also https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

To the comment from @remonh87
If you want exact `'false'` parsing you can use

```dart
extension BoolParsing on String {
  bool parseBool() {
    if (this.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
      return true;
    } else if (this.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
      return false;
    }
    
    throw '"$this" can not be parsed to boolean.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, maybe: `bool b = val.toLowerCase() == true.toString().toLowerCase();` if you're weird enough to go to such extents.

Comment: It's not really weird to not want to store a bunch of constants around your app like "true" when this should just be handled with a provided parse method. It's "weird" we have to write this pointless and repetitive code at all...

Dart would be a vastly better language to work with if they realized how important serialization is for real-world apps and made it more of a first-class operation. It's just cludge after cludge, be it enums, object serialization, or the most basic thing in the world, a bool. C# got this right, and so many sharp corners exist in dart because they didn't.

Comment: @shawnblais I don't necessarily disagree, but you should be aware that C# started about 15 years earlier and probably had much more resources from the beginning. Dart also does some things very well that C# can't or very poorly like compiling to C#, not sure about hot reload, and probably others, and probably more in the future. C# in Linux is still poor, ...

Comment: Oh yes, there is a lot that is nicer in dart than in c#, I didn't mean to really pit them against eachother. It's just such a shame that there is this huge hole of serialization/data classes in Dart, when so much prior art exists on the topic (like c#), because in the field, it's almost as important as a functioning http call stack. I can't think of a single application I've ever made, that did not need to serialize data to disk at some point. When basic things like enums/bools are not easily serializable... it's really annoying. Sounds like meta-programming may be coming to the rescue though!

Comment: I'm sure they'll improve a lot in the future. The last years was a lot about getting the foundation right. I agree with the Dart team that JSON should *not* be part of the language just because it's flavor of the year. Serialization needs improvement though. built_value always  worked very well for me and I assume they'll improve code generation to improve the situation.

Comment: I notice a small issue in this solution:  `"foo".parseBool()` will return in false while in that case I would like to see an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @remonh87 I updated my answer to demonstrate exact false handling instead of everything that's not `"true"` is treated as false.

Answer (score 35):

No. Simply use:

```dart
String boolAsString;
bool b = boolAsString == 'true';
```

Comment: I used this on a Checkbox State value and was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot perform this operation as you describe `bool.parse('true')` because Dart SDK is a lightweight as possible.

Dart SDK is not so unified as, for example, NET Framework where all basic system types has the following unification.

```dart
IConvertible.ToBoolean
IConvertible.ToByte
IConvertible.ToChar
IConvertible.ToDateTime
IConvertible.ToDecimal
IConvertible.ToDouble
IConvertible.ToInt16
IConvertible.ToInt32
IConvertible.ToInt64
IConvertible.ToSByte
IConvertible.ToSingle
IConvertible.ToString
IConvertible.ToUInt16
IConvertible.ToUInt32
IConvertible.ToUInt64
```

Also these types has `parse` method, including `Boolean` type.

So you cannot to do this in unified way. Only by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Since Dart 3.0 there is a `parse` method on `bool` type:

```dart
@Since("3.0")
external static bool parse(String source, {bool caseSensitive = true});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually yes, there is!

It's as simple as

```
bool.fromEnvironment(strValue, defaultValue: defaultValue);
```

Keep in mind that you may need to do `strValue.toLowerCase()`

Comment: According to the documentation, `fromEnvironment` returns true if the String is `true`. Weirdly enough, in practice this does not work. `bool.fromEnvironment` always returns false even when the input string is `true`.

Comment: 'fromEnvironment' returns an environment variable value, it doesn't return whether 'strValue' contains true or false.