# Flutter converting String to Boolean

Tags: string, flutter, dart, boolean

I am having a **String** that i would like to convert to **Boolean** Below is how the string looks like

```
String isValid = "false";
```

The String `isValid` can either be `true` or `false`

Is there a way i can directly convert this **String** isValid to **Boolean**. I have tried [Sample questions and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133935/in-dart-is-there-a-parse-for-bool-as-there-is-for-int) but they are just converting Strings which are hard coded, for example most of the answers are just when the string is `true`

Answer (score 6):

On top of my head, you can create an extension method for `string` data-type for your own need with all sorts of requirements checks and custom exceptions to beautify your desired functionalities. Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:test/expect.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  String isValid = "true";

  print(isValid.toBoolean());
}

extension on String {
  bool toBoolean() {
    print(this);
    return (this.toLowerCase() == "true" || this.toLowerCase() == "1")
        ? true
        : (this.toLowerCase() == "false" || this.toLowerCase() == "0"
            ? false
            : throwsUnsupportedError);
  }
}
```

Here, in this example, I've created a variable named `isValid` in the main() method, which contains a `string` value. But, look closely at how I've parsed the `string` value to a `bool` value using the power with `extension` declared just a few lines below.

Same way, you can access the newly created `string-extension` method **`toBoolean()`** from anywhere. Keep in mind, if you're not in the same file where the **`toBoolean()`** extension is created, don't forget to import the proper reference.

Bonus tips:
You can also access **`toBoolean()`** like this,

```
bool alternateValidation = "true".toBoolean();
```

Happy coding

Comment: I cannot believe there is no functionality to convert the primitive types out of the box in dart.

Answer (score 3):

This example can work for you, either if is `false` or `true`:

```
  String isValid = "true";
  
  bool newBoolValue = isValid.toLowerCase() != "false";
  
  print(newBoolValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

I opened a PR for this question, I believe that in the future it will be possible to do something native.

```dart
void main() {
  
  print(bool.parse("true")); // true
  print(bool.parse("false")); //false
  print(bool.parse("TRUE")); // FormatException
  print(bool.parse("FALSE")); //FormatException
  print(bool.parse("True", caseSensitive: false)); // true
  print(bool.parse("False", caseSensitive: false)); // false
  
  if(bool.parse("true")){
    //code..
  }

}
```

#### Reference

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/pull/51026

Answer (score 0):

You can use extensions like this

```
bool toBoolean() {
   String str = this!;
   return str != '0' && str != 'false' && str != '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All
You should make the string to lowercase to prevent check the string twice
then you can check if the string equal "true" or not and save the result to bool variable as below:

```
String isValidString = "false";  // the boolean inside string  
bool isValid = isValidString.toLowerCase() == 'true'; // check if true after lowercase
print("isValid=$isValid"); // print the result
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write

```
isValid.parseBool()
```

To convert String into bool.